# java enum inside class with label

Tags: java, enums

How can I create enum in class with labels?
If enum is single java file it is simple, i need to create String variable and then consctructor and getter and setter like this:

```
public enum Status {
    OPENED("opened"), CLOSED("closed");

    private Status(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public String label;

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }
}
```

But what if I have enum in class, how can i implement it?

```
public class Shop {

     private enum Status {
        OPENED("opened"),CLOSED("closed");
   } 

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the enum constructor and the enum member, just as you're defining a top-level enum.

```
public class Shop {
    private enum Status {
        OPENED("opened"),CLOSED("closed");

        private Status(String label) {
            this.label = label;
        }

        public String label;

        public String getLabel() {
            return label;
        }
    } 
}
```

This will compile just fine.

Note that the enums, nested in a class, a **implicitly static** by default. This way you don't need a `Shop` instance, but you can access the nested enum with:

```
Shop.Status opened = Shop.Status.OPENED;
```